# How to synchronize a music player to multiple clients in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, mp3

i've written a script to basicly synchronize a song to multiple clients. The problem is, client 1 will always be a tiny bit further into the song than client 2.

when client 1 is playing a song, and client 2 presses a button, client 1 sends the current time to client 2 so that client 2 can pick up the time and play the mp3.

I have tried to pre-load the mp3, so that the client 2 wont lose time loading the file when the song starts. Yet it is still +- 0.5seconds too late.

//Client

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentId = "";

    document.getElementById("audio").load();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/retrieveId',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
        currentId = data;
        console.log(currentId);
        }
    });


    $('#host').click(function () {
        $('#audio')[0].play();
        var interval2 = setInterval(function() {
            var currTime = document.getElementById('audio').currentTime;
            $.ajax({
            url: '/startedPlaying',
            type: 'post',
            data: { time: currTime, minute: '10' },
            success: function(data) {
            }
            });
        },10);
    });

    $('#client').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("audio").play();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/retrieveTime',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("audio").currentTime = data;
            }
        });
    })
});
```

//Server

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
}).listen(12340);


app.post("/startedPlaying", function(req, res) {
currTime = req.body.time;
res.end();
});

app.post("/retrieveTime", function(req, res) {
res.send(currTime);
res.end();
});

app.post("/retrieveId", function(req, res) {
id++;
res.send(id.toString());
res.end();
});
```

So basicly, i need help on how i should let them run exactly at the same time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't actually play at *exactly* the same time.  Even if you could start them at the same time, they have different clocks and will drift over time and need correction.  What are your requirements, exactly?  If you can deal with +/- 100ms, then you could do a WebRTC connection between clients to send timing data, and then use the playback speed to drift them back into sync.

Comment: My sole requirement is that they play at the same time. This is to make sure that the song will play on 2 or more devices. I am going to try to use Time, hopefully this works. Thank you though!

EDIT: would it work better to use TCP connections instead of using ajax requests?

Comment: Yeah, but what is "same time" to you?  Because if you're looking for things to be sample-accurate in-sync, I'm telling you that this isn't possible.  If you can deal with a few milliseconds, then you can get closer.

Comment: Well, since it plays songs on different clients, it should be synchronized. otherwise it doesnt have any meaning if client one is +- 0.5seconds earlier than client 2.
I'll give WebRTC a try.

Comment: I'm asking you, how close to synchronized do they have to be?  Because "perfect" doesn't exist in this scenario.

Comment: Ohh appologies. Well i'd say max 100ms.

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470120/c-sharp-action-problem-with-already-declared-body as we were just starting to be able to help. You should undelete it and try us again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is set up a channel of communication between the two clients that will be synchronized.  Given your latency requirements, I'm guessing that these clients are physically near each other and are likely to be on the same network.  In that case, you would benefit from creating a peer-to-peer WebRTC connection with data channel between them.  Generally, the clients can negotiate a connection across the network they share rather than having to send data out to the server and back, which reduces the latency of this data channel.

Next, buffer the media like you normally would.  You can use [`.buffered`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/buffered) to determine what time ranges have been buffered.  You can generally rely on the [`canplaythrough` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event) to determine when the player has buffered enough to play without having to rebuffer again.

Then, decide which end will be "master", from where all the synchronization data will come from.  Start playback on both sides.

Regularly, as playback is progressing, the master should send its [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) to the other clients.  Upon receiving, those clients should check their own `currentTime` to see how far away they are.  From there, they should make a calculation as to how to catch up.  For example, if the master is at `100.100` and a slave client is at `100.000`, then it needs to make up 100 milliseconds.  If you set the [`playbackRate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate) to `1.01`, you'll make up that time over 10 seconds.  Or, `1.02` and you'll make it up in 5 seconds.

You'll want to come up with some formula that determines the severity of the desynchronization and eases into fixing it.  You will also want some sane limits on that playback speed.  (For example, you probably don't want to go faster/slower by more than 10% to synchronize.)  Additionally, if the two are separated badly enough, you might choose to pause one, set the `currentTime` on the other (which usually causes some rebuffering) and start again.

An improvement you can make is to also determine the latency between the master/slave.  If the master says "now is 12.345s", and you receive that 100 milliseconds later, this timestamp is actually 12.445.  You can implement a "ping" of sorts where the latency is continuously measured.  Better yet, piggy back this on each timing message.

This should get you really close in timing, sufficient for most use cases.

Comment: Wow thanks, this surely helps. I'm going to look into WebRTC asap and post if i got any closer.

Comment: I used WebRTC and it works correctly. The sole problem is that it still differs, the difference is extremely low, yet you hear a slight echo. Other than that, it works!

Comment: You implemented this algorithm to allow it to drift back in-sync?

Comment: I haven't tried to since i currently don't have a lot of free time. Currently i'm simply adding 0.2s on the client when setting the music player. this makes it really close. Gonna try an actual algorithm asap. thank you

Comment: @gauthiercremers can you post a link to your code, or an example?

Answer (score 0):

There might be an MDN specification for this as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389954/how-to-sync-html5-audio-across-browsers), but it looks like there are few examples, and the few there are look to be behind a paywall

Current attempts have a large variety of delay but wanted to offer more perspective, tested with a macbook and an iphone, maybe someone could add to this

Getting over permission limitations, by first clicking an audio element on each browser before actually starting the test

[socket.io cdn](https://cdn.socket.io/4.7.4/socket.io.min.js)

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<h1>DEMO</h1>
<script src="/socket.io.js"></script>
<audio src="./test.m4a" autoPlay="" playsinline="" controls></audio>
<audio id="player" src="./test.m4a" autoPlay="" playsinline=""></audio>
<div   id="button" class="button">PLAY</div>

<script>
async function main(){
    // connect
    const socket = io()
    const button = document.getElementById("button")
    // on m4a loaded show play button
    player.addEventListener("canplaythrough",()=>{
        document.getElementById("button").style.display="block"
    })
    if (player.readyState > 3) {
        document.getElementById("player").style.display="block"
    }
    // on play
    button.addEventListener("click", async ()=>{
        socket.emit("message")
    })
    // on start recieved
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
            console.log(message)
            player.play()
    })
    socket.on("seek",()=>{
        console.log("seek")
        player.currentTime = 1
    })
}
main()
</script>

<style>
.button{
    display  : none;
    font-size: 15px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

server.js

```js
const express    = require('express')
const app        = express()
const http       = require('http')                                    // Http server that can be extended
const httpServer = http.createServer(app)                             // Serve API with http server
const { Server } = require("socket.io")                               // Crete nice websockets server
const io         = new Server(httpServer,{cors:                       // Extend http server with websockets
    {origins: ["http://localhost:5173"], methods: ["GET", "POST"]}})  // Allow dev server to access to websockets too
io.events        = {"info":"info"}                                    // Define events for ws
const cors       = require('cors')

async function main(config) {
    const viewPath  = config.dist
    const port      = config.port

    app.use(express.json()) 
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use(cors()) 
    app.use(express.static(viewPath))

    // Websockets
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {   
        var address = socket?.handshake?.address
        
        socket.on("message",()=>{
            console.log("Recieved message")
            io.emit("message", "hey")
            setTimeout(()=>{io.emit("seek", "hey")}, 4000)
        })
        socket.conn.on("close", (reason) => {
            console.log(`Client ${address} disconnected, Reason: ${reason}`)
        })
    })
    httpServer.listen(port, ()=>{
        console.log(`Running the server on port ${port}`)
    })
}

main({
    port : 8080,
    dist: "."
})
```