# How to sync HTML5 audio across browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, html5-audio

I have audio (mp3s) that has to start at fairly precise timestamps. I selected the timestamps in Chrome, only to realize that they load to a different place in Firefox and Safari. By 30 minutes in, the difference is about 5 seconds. Does anyone have experience with this, is it possible to make these run at the same rates? I just want the timestamp to match the content across browsers...

Example: https://dtak.github.io/dharmaseed-topics/archive/interface/index.html

Comment: The example is missing now

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the `TimingObject` could work very well for your use case. It's meant to synchronize a timeline across browsers and/or devices.

I once made a demo which shows how to synchronize a video but the very same technique also works for audio elements.

https://chrisguttandin.github.io/video-synchronization-demo/

The demo uses the [`timing-object`](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/timing-object), [`timing-provider`](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/timing-provider) and [`timingsrc`](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/timingsrc) libraries. The full source code is available on GitHub but the short version would somehow looks like this:

```
import { TimingObject } from 'timing-object';
import { TimingProvider } from 'timing-provider';
import { setTimingsrc } from 'timingsrc';

const timingObject = new TimingObject(
    new TimingProvider('your-client-id')
);

timingObject.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    if (timingObject.readyState === 'open') {
        setTimingsrc(
            document.getElementById('your-audio-element'),
            timingObject
        );
    }
}
```

To start the audio element you would then use the `TimingObject` like this:

```
timingObject.update({ velocity: 1 });
```

When running this code in multiple tabs/browsers/devices they should all play the same audio as long as the autoplay policy doesn't stop them.

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me trying to synchronize the playback of multiple long audio files.

Answer (score 0):

MP3 files don't actually have timestamps in their streams.  It's just a series of MPEG frames, with no timing information at all.

Seeking to a time offset in the stream requires calculating the byte offset, usually by looking at the bitrate of the first frame, and multiplying that by the number of samples per frame.  This is problematic because a variable bitrate may have been used to generate the stream.

A less efficient way is to actually seek through the entire stream, frame by frame.  This will be more accurate but requires going through the whole file.

Different players will use different methods, which is probably why you're seeing differences in timing.  The solution is to use a container format that actually supports timing information.

You can wrap your MP3-encoded audio inside an MP4/ISOBMFF file.  This will give you the timestamps you need, while not requiring transcoding.  Ideally though, go back to the original audio sources and encode with a better codec such as AAC and put that in your MP4.  Or, consider Opus in WebM.